# Alternative way of getting the called class in PHP

Tags: php

Is there an alternative way other than debug_backtrace() to know the name of the class that is calling my script?

Comment: No, nor is there any good reason why you should need this

Comment: yes, you can to `try{ throw \Exception() }catch(\Exception $e){ $e->getTrace(); }` but `debug_backtrace()` is faster

Comment: For instance I have an object: object(Opportunity)#3 (7) {
  ["connection":protected]=>
  object(Connection)#4 (5) { ......}} and I want to grab the 'Opportunity' word only from it. Can I do so without debug_backtrace()?

Comment: If you need help pulling it out of the backtrace I can help you with that.  Check out this class in my Evo framework  https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Evo/blob/master/Evo/Debug.php  Specifically the trace() method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the current class name, you can use get_class();
If the call stack involves many classes, and you want the first one for example, then you really have to use debug_backtrace().

```
$className = get_class($this);
```

Comment: The OP wants the class that called another class, from within the 'another' class

Comment: Thad did it. Cheers.

Comment: @ao-pack - you should word your question better... just saying.  Doesn't matter my backtrace function is still brilliant .. lol

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix indeed it is , just improved my own 'prettyStack'.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know back_trace is the best way.  That said, if you want to get the class / file etc that called a script you can use this function

```
 /**
 * get the line this file was called on ( +1 )
 * @param number $offset
 * @return array
 */
function trace($offset = 0)
{
    $trace = debug_backtrace(false);
    foreach ($trace as $t) {
        if ($t['file'] != __FILE__) {
            break;
        }
        ++$offset;
    }
    return array_slice($trace, ($offset - count($trace)));
}
```

Basically as you iterate through the backtrace, you're looking for the item before the current file.

You can also set `$offset` if you want it say 1 location before the one that called the trace() function.

https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Evo/blob/master/Evo/Debug.php